# How to control the icon on a WebView window on Windows 10

Tags: go, webview

Using WebView with Go (1.17.1) on Windows 10, I would like to control the Window icon and cannot figure out how it can be done. I don't mean the application icon. I have that using goversioninfo. But the icon that is on the pop-up window and also the taskbar for that window. Right now, I get a generic system-like icon. If it just used the application icon, that would work too.

Given:

```
debug := true
w := webview.New(debug)
defer w.Destroy()
w.SetTitle("Settings")
w.SetSize(800, 600, webview.HintNone)
w.Navigate(url)
w.Run()
```

Looking for:

```
w.SetIcon("/assets/icon.ico")
```

Even if I have to hack the Win32 API is fine. But I've not had success with that given what's out there...

Could it be that it cannot be done?

Answer (score 0):

In case Go has not implemented the `SetIcon` function, you can check the **webview.go** file : https://github.com/webview/webview/blob/94445826073456f76639696eb371488cf15ab3b1/webview.go

**Check this issue :** https://github.com/webview/webview/issues/28